# Get week from current_date and create a table with dynamic name in SQL

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, create-table, hue

I run a particular query every week that creates a weekly table of the required data.

The table names are in the format as mentioned below

1. db_name.subscriptions_wk29   -- a table created for week 29 data
2. db_name.subscriptions_wk30   -- a table created for week 30 data
3. db_name.subscriptions_wk31   -- a table created for week 31 data

Since this is a repetitive task I want to schedule this query so that it will automatically run on every monday of a particular week to get previous week's data.

The problem that I am facing is, I dont know how do I change the my table name dynamically as I run my query every week.

So when I run my query next time it should automatically create a table with name `db_name.subscriptions_wk32`. I can get value 32 from `weekofyear('2019-08-05')` but dont know how to put it in table name

Currently I write it as below

```
CREATE TABLE db_name.subscriptions_wk30 AS -- a hardcoded name
  SELECT *
  FROM ..........
```

What I want is

```
CREATE TABLE db_name.subscriptions_wkCAST(weekofyear('2019-08-05') AS varchar) -- a dynamic name
      SELECT *
      FROM ..........
```

Which will result into

CREATE TABLE db_name.subscriptions_wk32
          SELECT *
          FROM ..........

PS I am using Hive/Hue as RDBMS

Comment: what I understand is that you want that specific job will run on each Monday and get current week out of current date. such as 32 for select weekofyear('2019-08-05'); and then you need to pass 32 to your create table statement. Right?

Comment: Absolutely correct. A minor variation is that I want previous week and not current week in table name

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to calculate table name in the query itself, but it is possible to pass parameter to the script.
You can calculate parameter in a shell and execute script from shell:

```
#You can provide date:
varDate=2019-08-05

#And calculate weekyear
weeknumber=$(date --date=${varDate} +%V)
echo "${weeknumber}"
#returns 32

#Or calculate current date weekyear
weeknumber=`date +%V`

#Or calculate previous week date
weeknumber="$(date -d "7 days ago" +"%V")" 

#And call hive script like this:
hive -e "CREATE TABLE db_name.subscriptions_wk${weeknumber} -- parametrized name suffix
      SELECT *
      FROM ...
"
```

Or you can use `-hivevar` parameter in the hive command line to call script file (`-f` option), suppose `weeknumber` is already calculated like before:

```
hive -hivevar weeknumber="$weeknumber" -f script_file_name
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below shell to create a dynamic weekly table and can schedule it to run on every Monday using oozie scheduler or as a cron job.

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "Executing the hive query - get current week and store it in shell variable"

#current_week=$(hive -e "select weekofyear(current_date);")
#echo $current_week

previous_week=$(hive -e "select weekofyear(date_sub(current_date, 7));")
echo $previous_week
hive --hiveconf dbname=test_dev_db --hiveconf weekname=$previous_week -f hdfs://xxx.host.com:8020/user/xxx/dev/hadoop/hivescripts/createweektable.hql

echo "Executing the hive query - ends"


hive (test_dev_db)> desc test_dev_db.subscriptions_wk31;
OK
user_id                 int
country                 string
last_modified_date      date
Time taken: 0.345 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
```

**Update-**
This is how you can refer your shell variable in your hql script.

```
CREATE TABLE ${hiveconf:dbname}.subscriptions_wk${hiveconf:weekname}
row format delimited
fields terminated by '|'
STORED AS ORC
AS select * from test_dev_db.test_data;
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this!  Having multiple parallel tables with the same structure is a really bad idea.

Instead, have a single table `db_name.subscriptions` and add a column that specifies the week -- perhaps the first Monday or last Sunday of the week.

Then, instead of creating separate tables, just insert rows for each week.

You will find advantages to having a single table:

- The database will not be cluttered with lots of tables with similar names.
- SQL statements that run on the report can run on any week by changing the `where` clause (which can be parameterized) rather than changing the `from` clause (which cannot be).
- It is easy to write queries that look at changes over time.
- It is easy to see what weeks are available by querying the table.

And making the weeks partitions in the same table is very useful, if each week produces a non-trivial number of rows.

Comment: A partition column will allow to load and reload partition not touching other weeks and in parallel